# J.E. Hoffman's paper on Fermat's work

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

In the book [Number Theory: An Approach through History](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9780817645656) by André Weil, a reference is given on page 42 :

"J. E. Hofmann, Neues über Fermats zahlentheoretische Herausforderingen von 1657, Abh.d.preuss.Akad.d.Wiss. 1943-1944, Nr.9, pp. 41- 
47."

I'm looking for the above paper, either downloadable or purchasable copy.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can find it in JSTOR, for about $44 US dollars. Better: as it from the interacademic library exchange (or whatever that's called where you study) in your school

Comment: See J.E.Hofmann, [Über zahlentheoretische Methoden Fermats und Eulers](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00327401), *Archives* (1960).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, will take a look.